# parallel execution of files

Tags: c#, php, xml

below is my problem

1. I have '1' folder called 'dts' in server. It contains .xml files (numbers of files may differs in each run)
2. Those xml files contains database table values.
3. In the website this files executed using php. i.e., using PHP xml table values are imported to server database.
4. My task is to call these PHP files( those are used to do above task) using 'C#' in desktop utility.
5. I am executing this successfully.
6. Consider if that 'dts' folder contains more xml files it's takes lots of time to complete the task.

Is there any way to call more than 1 xml file using c#

Answer (score 1):

use threading with c#, c# has support of threading, or simple call multiple instance of the request

Comment: database tables means they depends some other tables. If we use threading we don't know which thread is running which is not. It creates some other problem so i'm not using threading, Any other options

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [Task Parallel library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to call the PHP files is parallel. eg Try using [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx)

```
// Parallel equivalent
Parallel.ForEach(sourceCollection, item => Process(item));
```